# Using C Print all the most frequent elements in a list

Tags: c

Sample input:
3 4 6 3 3

Expected output:

3

3

3

(printing all the most frequent numbers)

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//Program to count most occuring element
int findMostFrequentElement(int A[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)    //Sort the array
    {    
        int temp;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) 
        {     
           if(A[i] > A[j]) 
           {    
               temp = A[i];    
               A[i] = A[j];    
               A[j] = temp;    
           }     
        }     
    }        
    //finnd the most occuring element
    int max_count = 1, res = A[0], count = 1; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { 
        if (A[i] ==A[i - 1]) 
            count++; 
        else { 
            if (count > max_count) { 
                max_count = count; 
                res = A[i - 1]; 
            } 
            count = 1; 
        } 
    }   
    // If last element is most frequent 
    if (count > max_count) 
    { 
        max_count = count; 
        res = A[n - 1]; 
    }   
    return res; //return the most repeatinng  element
}
//Driver Program
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n;              //Array Size Declaration
    printf("Enter the number of elements ");
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int array[n];      //Array Declaration
    printf("Enter the array elements");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)   //Initializing Array Elements
    {
        array[i] = atoi(argv[2]);
    } 
    int maxElement = findMostFrequentElement(array, n);    //Function call
    printf("\n Maximum Repeating Element : %d",maxElement);   //Prints the most occuring element 
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? My count isn't printing all the most frequent numbers but instead is just printing the most frequent number. I'm trying to do it using arguments and not scanf

Comment: What is `array[i] = atoi(argv[2]);` supposed to do? Shouldn't it be `atoi(argv[i]);`? And the for should be `for (int i = 2; i < n + 2; i++)`. There are probably a lot of other problems like this. You need to debug this.

Comment: To print more than one value, you need a second loop.

Comment: if you don't want to use scanf you need to use args , but you cannot add text like scanf does if you really want to add text like scanf you need to use getchar it makes your program wait for an entry. And you should tell us what's not working, do you have errors during compilation ?

Comment: What is the expected output with the input `3 4 6 3 3 4 4` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to get the inputs using arguments you should fix your `main` function because if you want to store the number of the array's elements in the array then you should also ignore the first element of array in your function `findMostFrequentElement`. If not, then store it in `n` and then get the elements! Your main problem is that you are not getting inputs for the elements of array and in the address of elements are some values that you haven't changed! `atoi` doesn't work like `scanf`. It should be used after you get the inputs for typecasting.

Second, after you find the most frequent number, you should count the number of times that it has occured so that you can print the most frequent number that many times using `for` or `while` which you have done. So, to fix it you should use something like:`for (int j=0;j<max_count;j++) printf("%d\n",res);` but if there could be several different numbers as output, I suggest that you add another `for` at the end of your function so that if there are other numbers that are frequent you can find them and print them.